# SequenceCases does something odd with RuleDelayed arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching, rule

I have a list of stuff.

```
list = {a, b, b, a, b, a, a, a, b, a};
```

I want to split it up into subsequences where a single `a` is followed by zero or more `b`s. It's a perfect job for [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
SequenceCases[list, {a, b ...}]
(* {{a, b, b}, {a, b}, {a}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}} *)
```

Now I can use a `RuleDelayed` argument to do something to each subsequence.

```
SequenceCases[list, seq : {a, b ...} :> f[seq]]
(* {f[{a, b, b}], f[{a, b}], f[{a}], f[{a}], f[{a, b}], f[{a}]} *)
```

Let's use this to consecutively number the subsequences.

```
count = 1;
SequenceCases[list, seq : {a, b ...} :> (count++ -> seq)]
(* {1 -> {a, b, b}, 4 -> {a, b}, 6 -> {a}, 7 -> {a}, 8 -> {a, b}, 10 -> {a}} *)
```

Wait, what? Maybe `Sow`/`Reap` can shed some light:

```
count = 1;
Last@Reap[
  SequenceCases[list, seq : {a, b ...} :> Sow[seq, count++]],
  _, Rule]

(* {1 -> {{a, b, b}}, 2 -> {{a, b}}, 3 -> {{a}}, 4 -> {{a, b}}, 
    5 -> {{a}}, 6 -> {{a}}, 7 -> {{a}}, 8 -> {{a, b}}, 9 -> {{a}}, 
    10 -> {{a}}}*)
```

For some reason it's evaluating the right-hand side of that rule for each subsequence that matches at all, but only keeping the ones that are the longest. There's nothing in the documentation that specifies what `SequenceCases` will do if a `RuleDelayed` argument has side effects, but this behavior is still quite surprising and seems undesirable.

(There is, at least, an easy work-around with `Map[Replace[rule]]`, but it's likely to be verbose and repetitive.)

Comment: maybe `count = 1;SequenceCases[list, seq : {a, b ...} :> (count++ -> seq),  Overlaps -> All]` can explain what is going on?

Comment: That seems like an explanation but it's also bizarre behavior, and might even qualify as a bug.

Answer (score 7):

```
count = 1;
SequenceCases[list, seq : {a, b ...} :> (count++ -> seq), Overlaps -> All]
```

> {1 -> {a, b, b}, 2 -> {a, b}, 3 -> {a},
> 4 -> {a, b}, 5 -> {a},
> 6 -> {a},
> 7 -> {a},
> 8 -> {a, b}, 9 -> {a},
> 10 -> {a}}

#### [`SequenceCases >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html)

[image]

Comment: +1.  In v12.x, the core of the algorithm can be seen in the definition of ``Language`SequencesDump`sequenceCasesPattern``.  First all possible sublists are found but then that result is possibly trimmed down depending upon the setting of `Overlaps`.  The present implementation is straight-forward, but as the question shows the extra sublists are wasteful at best and harmful at worst.